# UIImageView instances of NSPathStore2 leaked

Tags: ios, swift3, memory-leaks, uiimageview, uiimage

I am loading png images from the Document directory into an UIImageView. When using the xcode **Debug memory graph** it comes up with Memory issues:
`instances of NSPathStore2 leaked`
[image: instances of NSPathStore2 leaked]

I have heard that the instrument's leak tool can report false [leaks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7018906/1109316).

The memory seems to not go up:
[image]

The problem seems to be in UIImage, see Instruments Leak report:
[image]

Here is the code that produces the images:

```swift
           try FileManager.default.copyfileToUserDocumentDirectory(forResource: "smiley", ofType: ".png")

            var fullPathString = ""
            if let docDir = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory,
                                                                .userDomainMask,
                                                                true).first {
                let fileName = "smiley.png"
                let fullDestPath = URL(fileURLWithPath: docDir).appendingPathComponent(fileName)
                fullPathString = fullDestPath.path
            }

            mainStackView.addArrangedSubview(UIImageView(image: UIImage(contentsOfFile: fullPathString)))
            mainStackView.addArrangedSubview(UIImageView(image: UIImage(contentsOfFile: fullPathString)))
```

The working project producing this problem can be found here: [UIImageViewNSPathStore2leaked](https://github.com/Quobject/UIImageViewNSPathStore2leaked)

Is there a way to change the code so that these leaks go away, or is this one of those false reports?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have the issue too.

#### Reproduce

Just create clean new project to reproduce the issue.

1. Drag image.png to project, make sure it in **Copy Bundle Resources**.
2. Write these two lines in viewDidLoad.

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "image", ofType: "png")!
        let _ = UIImage(contentsOfFile: path)
    }
}
```

3. Build and Run it.
4. Click **Debug Memory Graph** when viewController appeared.
5. You can see leak issues.

Not sure is it a bug of `init(contentsOfFile:)`?

#### Solution

I changed the API `init(data:)` instead of `init(contentsOfFile:)` to solve the problem.

```swift
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "image", withExtension: "png")!
let imageData = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
let _ = UIImage(data: imageData)
```

Using Xcode 11.5/11.3.1 and Swift 5

Comment: I have the same question, But why? instances of NSPathStore2 leaked is caused by `init(contentsOfFile:)`

Comment: Seems like a bug in Instruments, perhaps a false positive. In Xcode 12 beta 6 this no longer shows up as a leak.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like a bug in Instruments, perhaps a false positive. In Xcode 12 beta 6 this no longer shows up as a leak.

Just to note, in Xcode 11.6/11.7, the "leak" also happens with `UIImage(named: )` method:

[image: UIImage(named: ) leak.]

Comment: Still happens in the latest XCode (12.5.1), and also crashing my app in production